# Загрузка файла в плеер из MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, firebase

Я обучаюсь Android-разработке, и возник довольно интересный вопрос.

Можно ли реализовать загрузку файла из базы данных MySQL в приложение для Android? К примеру, для плеера.
Был бы очень рад ответу, и если возможно, хотя бы примерному алгоритму. Спасибо.

Comment: и где вы предполагаете располагать MySQL?

Comment: Алгоритм: делаете запрос в БД, загружаете файл, используете.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а как вы MySQL будете на Android устанавливать?.. даже если речь про удаленный сервер, Вы уверены что Dalvik поддерживает необходимые драйвера?.. там об обратной совместимости речи не идет, посколько используется достаточно урезанная версия виртуальной машины. И лично я по своему опыту чаще натыкался на драйвера, которые НЕ поддерживались Dalvik'ом

Comment: Чаще просто на сервере делают REST сервис или используют тот же Firebase

Comment: @МихаилРебров, Dalvik кончился вместе с Андроид 4, но это мало что меняет, согласен :) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, спасибо :-) Буду знать. Я ретроград....примерно в то время и работал с ним.